# Android WebView failed to load a particular URL

Tags: android

I am working on a android project. In that project i have to load a URL in WebView. 
  But I am unable to Load the particular URL (Any other URL is loading perfectly). I have also added INTERNET permission.  Though the URL open from Android browser .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog progDailog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
         progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading","Please wait...", true);
            progDailog.setCancelable(false);



           webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);



           webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
           webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
           webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
         //  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    progDailog.show();
                    view.loadUrl(url);

                    return true;                
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                    progDailog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl("https://XXXXX.com/");
    }
```

}

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: What is the actual URL you're trying to open ?

Comment: In Logcat i am not getting any error. It just show failed to load URL...Please check your Internet connection..... The page is become white

Comment: Give also an example with a working URL.

Comment: URL is https://easyfinancial.com/partner

Comment: Can you reach a different "https" url?

Comment: implement **onReceivedError** method..and identify what error is..

Answer (score 0):

This site might contain insecure content.Check your proxy settings for the WIFI network connection and make sure they are correct.